# iTerm2 "Cmd + Click" to open file doesn't work under Tmux session

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 with a Tmux session connecting to localhost Tmux server. On a normal iTerm2 window/tab, I can use `Cmd + Click` to open a file with its default app. However, it's not working in the Tmux session. Instead of opening the file in its default app, iTerm2 always opens it as a URL, in the default browser.

Does anyone know a fix to this? Or I'm having something wrong with my Tmux configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on apple.stackexchange.com:

> To use the normal mouse behavior in `tmux` you have to keep `alt` pressed. So click on the link while pressing `cmd`+`alt`. The same applies when selecting text.

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147129/111777

Answer (score -2):

exit tmux seesion first, click file with the mouse to open it via the default app.

then enter tmux session, it's ok.